# Understanding Endianess

Tags: c#, stack, endianness

I'm writing a stack class in C# that behaves like an x86 stack (word padding, ability to push and pop different sized "objects", etc.)

If I call `Push<int>(0x01234567)`, the ASCII art below depicts what should happen. Is this big-endian or little-endian.

```
| 0x01 | 0x23 | 0x45 | 0x67 |  ---- Low Address  (New  top)
   |      |      |      \----> 0x67
   |      |      \-----------> 0x45
   |      \------------------> 0x23
   \-------------------------> 0x01
                               ---- High Address (Orig top)
```

Comment: Have you looked at what big and little endian is on Wikipedia?  If you had, you'd have the answer already.

Comment: @TonyTheLion yes I have. I'm still confused on how it works with a stack.

Comment: Your picture doesn't really help much because we can't tell what's the high and what's the low address in memory on either of the boxes :)

Comment: @500-InternalServerError updated image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The least significant byte (0x67) is in the lowest address, so little endian.

Answer (score 1):

Are those the individual bytes of the `int` value or is that just a strange way to display the `int`'s hex representation in chunks? Because in little-endian the least significant byte has the lowest memory address, i.e. it comes first in a raw hexadecimal view of the bytes in memory. On your stack, however, that first byte is stored in the highest address, which would be big-endian then.

Comment: Those are the individual byte values

Comment: Ok, in that case the value 0x01234567 should be written as the bytes 0x67 0x45 0x23 0x01, because that's the order of bytes in memory on Intel systems. The order of bytes in your stack is correct, though.

Comment: The stack as it is in your image is little endian if you pushed 0x01234567.